# Birth simulator

Tags: java, random

I'm working on a program that is supposed to select random numbers (with half being assigned as boys and the rest are girls) and should stop when at least one boy and one girl has been selected, then print out the total babies. It looks a little like this:

```
public class BoyAndGirl {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int boy = 0;
        int girl = 0;
        int total = boy + girl;

        while (boy <= 1) && (girl <= 1){
            if (Math.random() < 0.5);
            boy = boy + 1;
            if (Math.random() >= 0.5);
            girl = girl + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have a total of " + total + " babies!");
    }
}
```

I know I must be missing some code to actually begin the random sequence, but I'm not sure how to start it. Or, on the other hand, should I be using a boolean statement?

Comment: You need to remove the semicolon from `if (Math.random() < 0.5);` and the line two lines below that.

Comment: `while (boy <= 1) && (girl <= 1){` does that even compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the code I can see the following issues:

1) The following computes the sum using the then-current values of `boy` and `girl` (both of which are zero). The sum is then never updated.

```
  int total = boy + girl;
```

2) The `while` condition is wrong logically and is missing parentheses around it. I'll let you figure out how to fix the condition.

3) To make a single selection between two mutually exclusive outcome (boy/girl), call `Math.random()` just once rather than twice. Otherwise you're not ensuring that the outcome are mutually exclusive (i.e. you could get both boy and girl on the same iteration, or neither boy nor girl).

4) There are extraneous semicolons at the end of the `if` statements. This is a subtle one: the code is syntactically correct but doesn't do what you'd expect (both increments are executed irrespective of what `Math.random()` returns).

These are easy to fix. By and large you are almost there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did all the things you've suggested and now it's finally printed the number of babies.

Comment: @DarronMartinez: My pleasure. Thanks for asking a well-presented first question.

Comment: @DarronMartinez: If NPE's answer helped you solve your question, consider marking it as the "correct" answer by clicking the large check mark to the left of it.